# How can i change Error message?

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I'm using worksheet protection IWorksheet.ProtectContents. If i try to change something there is message: "Locked cells cannot be modified when protection is enabled". So is there a way to change text and title of this message or though hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the WorkbookView.[ShowError](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.WPF~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls.WorkbookView~ShowError_EV.html)(...) event, which would give you the chance to prevent certain error messages from popping up or provide your own custom message.  Example:

```
private void workbookView_ShowError(object sender, SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls.ShowErrorEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Message == "Locked cells cannot be modified when protection is enabled.")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My custom message");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```